# Activity restart when configuration changes but I used viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Viewmodel class using hilt viewmodel and avoids configuration changes side effects

```
 @HiltViewModel
 class ListScreenModel @Inject constructor():ViewModel() {

 val myFlow=flow{
      (0..100).forEach{
          emit(it)
          kotlinx.coroutines.delay(1000)
      }
  }
}
```

Composable function where I use my viewmodel and try to print emitted values.

```
@Composable
fun ListValue() {
val viewmodel = hiltViewModel<ListScreenModel>()
val num=viewmodel.myFlow.collectAsState(initial = 0).value

Text(
    text = num.toString(),
    fontSize = 29.sp
)
}
```

MainActivity where I started my application

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        VOYAGENAVJETPACKCOMPOSETheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                // Navigator(screen = ListScreen())
                ListValue()
            }
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Activity will be restarted on configuration change unless you opt-out of specific configuration change(s) and handle them manually instead. That has nothing to do with ViewModels. A HiltViewModel does survive configuration changes, but what that actually means is that you get the same instance of the VM back after every configuration change, which you do. So the behavior you are seeing is the documented and expected behavior.

Comment: You also shouldn't change that behaviour unless you have good reason, the system uses it to make changes when required, and it's up to the developer to make sure stuff survives an Activity being recreated. `ViewModel`s were introduced in part to help with that, since they (and their data) get retained across different instances, so the new Activity can just hook into that and carry on where you left off